# insert SQL rows from a string with comma record-delimiter and colon-delimited name-value pairs

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

The data we receive is formatted like this:

```
'1:0,2:1,3:1,4:0'
```

The values are separated by commas: the value before the colon is a studentId, and after is a bit value.

I want to store these values in a temp table:

```
studentID   |   BitValue
1           |    0
2           |    1
3           |    1
4           |    0
```

How do I do this in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: have you tried anything...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @param = '1:0,2:1,3:1,4:0'

;WITH Split_Col 
AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<table><col>' + REPLACE(ColName,':', '</col><col>') + '</col></table>') AS xmlcol
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ColName  
        FROM  
        (
             SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(ColName, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS ColName  
             FROM  (SELECT @param AS ColName) TableName
         ) AS A CROSS APPLY ColName.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    ) TableName
)

 SELECT      
 xmlcol.value('/table[1]/col[1]','varchar(100)') AS studentID,    
 xmlcol.value('/table[1]/col[2]','varchar(100)') AS BitValue
 FROM Split_Col
```

**EDIT**

Assuming your Student Table has columns StudentId, Name. Find the updated query joining student table

```
SELECT ST.Name,SP.studentID,SP.BitValue FROM 
(
  SELECT   
 xmlcol.value('/table[1]/col[1]','varchar(100)') AS studentID,    
 xmlcol.value('/table[1]/col[2]','varchar(100)') AS BitValue
 FROM Split_Col
) SP
INNER JOIN Student ST on SP.studentID = ST.studentID
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7f95/1)

Comment: @Muhammad Jawad I'm glad my answer helped you

Comment: cay you please tell me how to join this CTE with our main query, Coz column names are confusing me in thi CTE.
we have to join this CTE with student table with both student id and bit value
thanks

Comment: and also tell me who to call these coulumns from our main query which joins this CTE?

Answer (score 2):

This works in **MS SQL Server 2008**.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
drop table #TempTable

create table #TempTable (studentID int, BitValue int)
declare @var nvarchar(max)
set @var='1:0,2:1,3:1,4:0'

set @var='insert into #TempTable values ('+REPLACE(REPLACE(@var,',','),('), ':', ',')+')'
exec (@var)

select * from #TempTable

drop table #TempTable
```

for **MS SQL Server 2005**, try:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
drop table #TempTable

create table #TempTable (studentID int, BitValue int)
declare @var nvarchar(max)
set @var='1:0,2:1,3:1,4:0'

--set @var=REPLACE(@var,',','),(')
set @var='insert into #TempTable values ('+REPLACE(REPLACE(@var,',','); insert into #TempTable values('), ':', ',')+')'
exec (@var)

select * from #TempTable

drop table #TempTable
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution in sql server 2005, coz its not working on 2005

Comment: can we do it with @t table instead of #table?

Comment: I think table variable will not be available outside its initial scope.

Comment: This solution is vulnerable to SQL Injection. It's worth looking into [responsible ways to use dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection).